# Not able to retrieve api data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

First of all, sorry if this is a long question, since it has `gist` links as well as long code blocks. 
I want to retrieve api data and display it in a `listview`. [This](https://gist.github.com/DK15/600fdb171e0b25c08f7e4ac071c791f4) is the json structure. [This](https://gist.github.com/DK15/e2c65dfb780b27c722cb5b6314ba894b) is the class representing the json. `Container` to display in UI:

```
Widget reviewsSection = Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _fetchReviews(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (reviewList != null) {
                return _buildReviewTiles();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify);
              }
              // By default, show a loading spinner
              return new Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            })
    );
```

And this is how I am fetching the data:

```
Future <Null> _fetchReviews() async {

    // Review URL
    final String url = 'https://..';

    // Authorization token
    final String auth = '';

    // Asynchronous JSON from server
    final response = await http.get(url + 'id=${this.pro.id}' + '&k=$auth');


    // If the request was successful
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        // Convert the JSON response to a list
      final parsed = json.decode(response.body);

        // Adds review objects to reviewList
      for (int i = 0; i < parsed.length; i ++) {
        reviewList.add(new Review.fromJSON(parsed, i));
      }
    }
    else {
      throw('HTTP request failed, statusCode: ${response?.statusCode}');
    }
  }

  // Updates reviewList
  Future<Null> _refresh() async {
    await _fetchReviews();
  }
```

Creating a `listview` based on the reviews:

```
  Widget _buildReviewTiles() {
    return (new Container(
        child: new RefreshIndicator(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: reviewList == null ? 0 : reviewList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new Container(
                      child: Center(
                          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                            _getReviewTile(reviewList[index]),
                          ])));
                }),
            onRefresh: _refresh
        )
    )
    );
  }
```

And [this](https://gist.github.com/DK15/783af00ade80f676ee670c61c7802cc9) returns the `list tile`. 
This is my first time dealing with apis in flutter. I tried debugging and got to know that size of `reviewsList` is 0, this could be the reason but am not sure, and tried to debug it more, so needed some help to fetch and display it properly.

Comment: are you debugging correctly?

Comment: @diegoveloper, Update: I made some changes to get close to the issue, like, used `SliverAppBar` widget to get collapsing toolbar experience and now getting multiple exceptions such as `Duplicate GlobalKeys detected in widget tree`, `A RenderSliverPadding expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox` while retrieving `reviews` data.

Comment: Another update: i did hot restart which made above exceptions go away, but the original issue remains same, unable to retrieve data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues there, you are using a FutureBuilder, but your method doesn't return anything.

You should change this :

```
 Future <Null> _fetchReviews() async {
```

To this:

```
Future <List< Review >> _fetchReviews() async {

   .....

  return reviewList;
}

Future<Null> _refresh() async {
   return await _fetchReviews();
 }
```

Change this method :

```
 Widget _buildReviewTiles() {
```

to this:

```
 Widget _buildReviewTiles(List<Review> list) {
```

And inside your `FutureBuilder` change this:

```
  FutureBuilder(
        future: _fetchReviews(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return _buildReviewTiles(snapshot.data);
          }
```